# Spark 1.3.1 - Parquet - Discovery Multiple Partitions on Save

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr, parquet

I have an ETL application that uses Spark 1.3.1, Amazon S3 and EMR 3.8.
I need my application to save a Dataframe in multiple partitions.

According to the Spark 1.3.1 documentation , this is the way to partition your parquet file:

[Partition Discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery)

```python
df1.save("data/test_table/key=1", "parquet")
```

But the problem is that my RDD has a lot of data and need to save on separate partitions. (in group)

I can't find a correct logic for this program to run quickly (or not so slow)

Some attempts :

```python
#Get All RDD Partition's 
AllPartitions = RDD.map(lambda x: x[0]).distinct()

#For all partitions save filtering 
for part in AllPartitions.collect():
   filteredDF = df.filter(df.recordOpeningDate == part)
   df.save(path=outputFilePath + "/FIELD=" + part, source='parquet',mode='append')
```

Trying using **GroupBy**

```python
def Mapping(line):
   return (
   line[0] , [ 
   #Definition of my RDD
    ])

def SavePartitions(KV):
   #WRONG ! I cant create a DF inside a transformation 
   df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(KV, SCHEMA)
   df.save(...)    

RDD = RDD.map(Mapping).groupByKey().mapValues(SavePartitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you have a `dataframe`, you can call `repartition` to split your data into the desired number of partitions, say 10:

```
myDataFrame.repartition(10).saveAsParquet("/path/to/output/")
```

This will result in your data being stored in 10 different files under /path/to/output/.

Comment: My solution was to update my clusters for EMR 4.0 (with Spark 1.4.1) and using method pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save.

Answer (score 0):

For information,

My solution was to update my clusters for EMR 4.0 (with Spark 1.4.1) and using method [pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save).